# Power Apps global variable value not updated

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I hope to get help for this. I'm new to power apps and I'm trying to create a global variable with value as the selected item from my gallery. But it does not update whenever I choose another item. I made sure to hit on Run OnStart while testing but it still doesn't update the value.

[image]

I've tried refreshing the data source, but I think it has nothing to do with the global variable.
I need an updated value of the global variable as the edit form on the next page is using that info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to use a variable? In any place in your app where you use `Var_DiscoveryMeeting_Selected` you can use `Gallery_DiscoveryMeeting.Selected` instead - and all properties that depend on that value will be recalculated whenever the selection of the gallery changes (Power Apps uses a primarily *declarative* language, where variables in many cases are not necessary).

If you really need to use a variable, then you can use the OnSelect property of the Gallery_DiscoveryMeeting itself, where you could have something like `Set(Var_DiscoveryMeeting_Selected, ThisItem)`. But if you don't need it, I wouldn't suggest doing so. For example, if you add a control inside a gallery, and need to handle its OnSelect property, you'll need to remember to invoke the OnSelect of the gallery in addition to doing what the control needs to do.

Comment: Thank you, Carlos! That worked without a global variable. Thank you so much!